# Guest program exited with non-zero exit code: 1

Tags: batch-file, vmware

I am working with the build /Release process,We implement the build system using the one host machine which has two Virtual machines.One is windows virtual machine and other Linux.During the build we are invoking Nightly.bat file from Windows vm and Nightly.sh from Linux .Iam using the following command...

```
start /b vmrun.exe -T ws -gu "End" -gp Password runProgramInGuest "D:\Windows VM\Windows 7 x64 Edition + Visual Studio 2008\Windows 7 x64 Edition.vmx" -activeWindow "C:\SPSBuild\Nightly.bat"
vmrun.exe -T ws -gu root -gp quasar runProgramInGuest "D:\Linux\RHEL 5.3 64-bit\RHEL 5.3 64-bit - Sreejith.vmx" "/home/quasar/workspace/SPSBuild/Nightlynew.sh"
```

But I got an error which shows "Guest program exited with non-zero exit code: 1"..
  The username ,password and the path is correct.
  Anybody have any idea about that...please give me an answer..

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like either "C:\SPSBuild\Nightly.bat" or "/home/quasar/workspace/SPSBuild/Nightlynew.sh" is failing and returning an error.

Can you run these scripts manually to see if they produce an error message?  Can you read the scripts to determine why they return exit code 1?

Answer (score 0):

The file must exists in the guest machine. If it does not exists, you need to use `copyFileFromHostToGuest` before `runProgramInguest`.